# Combining assets into a single file in Rails 4 development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to extract all vendor assets into separate file and serve them as a minified and combined file also in development environment. I could do that in Rails 3 by using `debug: false` in `javascript_link_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag` helpers like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "vendor",      :media => "all", :debug => false %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor",      :debug => false %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

That made Rails to serve me `vendor.js` and `vendor.css` as a minified and combined assets even in development environment. `application.js` and `application.css` were served as usually in development environment.

I can not achieve similar results in Rails 4, because if using the lines above, then this will be generated into html for every asset specified in `vendor` assets:

`<script debug="false"... ><script>`

How to achieve the same thing in Rails 4?

I have written a detailed blog post for Rails 3 about this feature at my blog. You can check it out if my question is not clear enough http://itreallymatters.net/post/45763483826/speeding-up-page-load-time-in-rails

Comment: Have you tried setting `config.assets.debug = false` in your `development.rb`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think that this will minify and concatenate my scripts too in development into application.js, although i don't want it. I want that to happen only with vendor scripts (like jquery, bootstrap and so on).

Comment: Be sure to check out [Half Pipe](https://github.com/d-i/half-pipe) with [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overall: Its a regression with Sprockets 2. Read on for an explanation and solution.

#### How Debugging works internally

Assume you have a file called `vendor.js` with the following:

```
# vendor.js
//= require jquery
//= require knockout
//= ... some more requires

function one() { }
function two() { }
// and some javascript code
```

First, let's see what the Asset Debugging does:

1. Places a single `<script src="vendor.js">` tag if debugging is disabled,

   (or)

   Places multiple `<script src="vendor.js?body=1">, <script src="jquery.js?body=1">, <script src="knockout.js?body=1">, ...` when debugging is enabled
2. The `body=1` is also an integral part of debugging. If you say `<script src="vendor.js?body=1">` - it *only* renders the javascript inside `vendor.js`. It doesn't include any of the other `require ...` code.

   But if you hit `vendor.js` alone, without the `?body=1`, it includes all the `require ...` code as well.

So a combination of the above two produce the necessary debugging output. What we want to do is, when we say `javascript_include_tag "vendor", :debug => false`, we want a single `<script src="vendor.js">` tag with *NO* `?body=1` appended.

#### Explaining the Regression

[The regressed code is here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/b522561d2d83b83c99e9aa54c8079fd1241fdf49/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb#L88). Specifically the buggy code is this one statement:

```
L88. if request_debug_assets?
```

Its checking request_debug_assets?, and then automatically setting `:debug => true` [further in line #92](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/b522561d2d83b83c99e9aa54c8079fd1241fdf49/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb#L92). But `request_debug_assets?` is returning true, because that is being set at the application configuration level.

This one statement should have ideally been:

```
L88. if request_debug_assets? && options["debug"] != false
```

#### Solution / Patch

I'll raise a pull request for the same, but until the pull request is reviewed and merged, you can do the following in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/sprockets_debug_patch.rb
module Sprockets::Rails::Helper

  def javascript_include_tag(*sources)
    options = sources.extract_options!.stringify_keys

    # CHECK options["debug"] as well, not just the global assets.debug
    if request_debug_assets? && options["debug"] != false
      # REST ALL SAME CODE AS ORIGINAL METHOD
```

Do the same for `stylesheet_include_tag` as well. Unfortunately there is no better way than copy/pasting the method code, but this resolves the problem.

Throughout `Sprockets::Rails::Helper` class, you will find that it says *all this will be deprecated in Sprockets 3.x*. I don't know if Rails 4 is scheduled to ship with Sprockets 3.x. If so, then these patches might end up not being required.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try in the next couple of days. I thought that this has to be some kind of a bug. Can you also provide the url for the issue so i could watch it?

Comment: @JarmoPertman, [raised issue #68](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/68) under sprockets-rails. The above patch will work meanwhile, until the issue is resolved...

Comment: This issue is fixed in sprockets-rails 2.0.1, but the current rails 4.0.1 still declares a squiggly dependency on 2.0.0, so you may no get it. To force 2.0.1 use "gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.0.1'".

Answer (score 6):

Another option if you don't want to use monkeypatch right now and you are just trying to work with your app without worrying about all of you assets is to set / change

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.compress = false
```

in config/development.rb

Comment: That solution does not work since it will also minify/concatenate my (non-vendor) scripts. This is not what i would want in development.

Comment: config.assets.compress = false    if you have this line enabled it will not compress anything. config.assets.debug = false - that will just stop recompiling. That's how I'm running my development. And I'm able to  make changes to my application.js.coffee and application.css.sass without any problem and see changes right away.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in sprockets-rails master and I'll release a new version soon. Meanwhile you can get the fix in your application pointing sprockets-rails to github in your Gemfile:

```
gem "sprockets-rails", github: "rails/sprockets-rails"
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Rails 4.2 and sprockets-rails 2.3.3 this is working:

```
config.asset.debug = false
```

and then:

```
?debug_assets=1
```